# Numbering chemical intermediate compounds with chemstyle

Tags: numbering, roman-numerals, chemstyle, bpchem

I´m currently writing my bachelor thesis in chemistry and chose to number my compounds with `chemstyle`. And except of one little issue that works just fine: Is it possible to number intermediate compounds with roman numerals beginning with "I", "II"....?
Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}

\begin{document}
\CNlabelnoref{cmpd:1}
\CNlabelnoref{cmpd:2}
\CNlabelnoref{cmpd:3}
\CNlabelnoref{cmpd:4}
\CNlabelsubnoref{cmpd:4}{one}
\CNlabelsubnoref{cmpd:4}{two}

\begin{scheme}[H]
  \schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd:1}
  \schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd:2}
  \schemeref[TMP3]{cmpd:3}
  \schemeref[TMP4]{cmpd:4}
  \schemerefsub[TMP5]{cmpd:4}{one}
  \schemerefsub[TMP6]{cmpd:4}{two}
  \includegraphics{test-tmp.eps}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: numbering works fine but I´d like to have an alternate numbering with roman numerals. the major compounds should be numbered from 1, 2, 3,... but a few exceptions should be  numbered from I, II, III, IV...
I hope you get what I´m up to

Comment: It's actually not `chemstyle` but (in your case) `bpchem` that does the numbering and defines the corresponding commands